# Attempted to read or write protected memory in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, exception

I'm trying to dynamically change connection string for Entity framework (v4.4) context, I get this error :

> System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
>
> Message: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

The code that causes the error looks something like the following (I changed the names).

```
private Project1.Data.Context _db;

public ConstructorMethod(string connectionString ="")
{
    _db = new Project1.Data.Context();
    _db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
}
```

It's an DAO class to hold the data access methods and on the constructor I want to pass the connection string but for some reason I can't get it to work. Is there some other way to acheive passing a connection string through the constructor ?

All the posts on this site about this error seem to be unrelated to EF.

**EDIT**
When trying in a seperate project with minimal code. I got the following error :

> Keyword not supported: 'metadata'

That led me to find the solution I'm posting below. I would still like to know why this was happening because it seems to work in MVC 4 applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an constructor that allows passing a connection string in the generated context class file solved my problem

```
public SomeContext(string connectionStringOrName)
        : base (connectionStringOrName)
    {
    }
```

I would still like to know why the error occured, as it does work as mentioned above on other projects using the same version of Entity Framework.